# In R, what's the most idiomatic way to find the maximal value of a vector before a position?

Tags: r, max

From a numeric vector, I want to obtain a vector of the same length containing the maximal value found until the position as value.

I can obtain such result using a for loop as in the example (or using Rcpp for faster results), but I was wondering if there was a more idiomatic way to do it or if a built-in function did already exist in some package.

```
vector <- c(1L,2L,3L,2L,2L,4L,5L,1L,2L,3L,6L,7L,3L)
initialMax <- -1L
result <- vector
N <- length(vector)

for(i in 1:N){
  if(vector[i]>initialMax){

    result[i:N] <- vector[i]
    initialMax <- vector[i]

  }
}
```

Comment: `max(vector[seq_len(N)])`

Comment: Your `result` is `cummax(vector)`, though I do not understand your opening sentence explaining the desired result, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm with @Frank on this one.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find an appropriate way to phrase the question. I was looking for `cummax` as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure what you exactly want. But here's my shot.

This gives you a `list()` with the max values going from beginning to end.

I think using `list()` and therefore `lapply` should bring you into an idiomatic direction using R.

Using the pipe from package `magrittr` here. Not idiomatic but makes things a whole lot easier.

```
seq_along(vector) %>% lapply(function(N)return(max(vector[1:N],na.rm=T)))
```